# Email with 2 multiparts shows as one

Tags: perl, email, multipart

I'm trying to figure out why my multi-part email all comes out as one:

[image]

The code I'm using to create 2 "parts" for my email, is:

```
  use Email::MIME;
  use Email::Address::XS;
  use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);

  # multipart message
  my @parts = (
      Email::MIME->create(
          attributes => {
              content_type => "text/plain",
              disposition  => "inline",
              charset      => "UTF-8",
          },
          body_str => "Hello there é!",
          attributes => {
                encoding => 'quoted-printable',
                charset  => "UTF-8",
          }
      ),
      Email::MIME->create(
          attributes => {
              content_type => "text/html",
              disposition  => "inline",
              charset      => "UTF-8",
          },
          body_str => "Hello there éíó!",
          attributes => {
                encoding => 'quoted-printable',
                charset  => "UTF-8",
          }
      )
  );

  my $email = Email::MIME->create(
      header_str => [
          From => 'andy@mysite.org',
          To => [ 'Name <andy@foo.com>' ],
          Subject => "foo"
      ]
  );
  $email->parts_set( \@parts );

  print $email->as_string;

  sendmail($email->as_string);
```

The email is sent and comes out like so:

```
Delivered-To: andy@foo.com
Received: by 10.223.130.5 with SMTP id 5csp329339wrb;
        Thu, 11 Jan 2018 01:09:17 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ACJfBotkcH6W0rsnQMkLx9pPqbt1rUgKaC9ShvWLQbn6u8muQbVnCjTCZRmf0d5RzegqW4AGpFHP
X-Received: by 10.28.92.146 with SMTP id q140mr474098wmb.5.1515661757887;
        Thu, 11 Jan 2018 01:09:17 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <andy@mysite.org>
From: andy@mysite.org
To: Name <andy@foo.com>
Subject: foo
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 09:09:17 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="15156617570.82fd1E.6414"
Message-Id: <E1eZYrN-0001fT-Hp@admin.myserver.org>

--15156617570.82fd1E.6414
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 09:09:17 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello there =C3=A9!
--15156617570.82fd1E.6414
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 09:09:17 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello there =C3=A9=C3=AD=C3=B3!
--15156617570.82fd1E.6414--
```

I can see the split "parts", but for some reason they show up together?

**UPDATE:** : I thought I had fixed this - I had 2 of these `attributes => { }` values for each `@part`, and that was causing the content_type to be text/plain as a default. So I now have:

```
  my @parts = (
      Email::MIME->create(
          body_str => "Hello there <b>é!</b>",
          attributes => {
                encoding => 'quoted-printable',
                charset  => "UTF-8",
                content_type => "text/plain",
                disposition  => "inline",
          }
      ),
      Email::MIME->create(

          body_str => "Hello there <b>éíó!</b>",
          attributes => {
                content_type => "text/html",
                disposition  => "inline",
                charset      => "UTF-8",
                encoding     => 'quoted-printable',
          }
      )
  );
```

...and the email comes out as:

```
From: andy@mysite.org
To: Name <andy@foo.com>
Subject: foo
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 09:45:21 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="15156639210.d5dF6bf.14583"


--15156639210.d5dF6bf.14583
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 09:45:21 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello there <b>=C3=A9!</b>


--15156639210.d5dF6bf.14583
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 09:45:21 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello there <b>=C3=A9=C3=AD=C3=B3!</b>


--15156639210.d5dF6bf.14583--
```

...but its still showing both the plain text and HTML parts at the same time. The weird part, is that if I put  tags around some of it, I get what I would expect:

[image]

...but it just shows them both side by side :/

Comment: Your updated code still has two sets of `attributes` in each call to `create()`.

Comment: @DaveCross - that is how they show to do it though? http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-MIME-1.946/lib/Email/MIME.pm#SYNOPSIS

Comment: Take a closer look at your original code and your "updated" code. There is no difference. The both have the doubled `attributes` key.

Comment: @Dave - oh, weird. I must have not copied and pasted the right version. I've updated it now.

Comment: Ok. It now looks like your code is generating the correct multi-part email - one plain text part and one HTML part. The fact that Gmail isn't displaying it how you want, is something you might have to take up with Google :-)

Comment: @DaveCross - yeah I still don't get why its not working. Maybe I'll take a break and come back to it ;) Will post once I have a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked it out by comparing an email that I knew worked as I was expecting, to mine.

The emails I was sending out, had:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="_----------=xxxxx"
```

But the working ones had:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_----------=xxxxx"
```

Sure enough, seeing the **multipart/mixed**, it now works fine:

```
$email->content_type_set( 'multipart/alternative' );
```

Comment: You don't need to use `content_type_set()`, you can use `attributes => { content_type => 'multipart/mixed' } }` when creating the wrapper MIME object. Or you could avoid all of this by using [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand what a multi-part email is. A multi-part email is a single email which is made up of many parts. Each part can be another email message or the contents of another file.

You have created a single email which contains a number of other emails.

If you want to send separate emails then you need to... well... send separate emails :-)

**Update:** Ok, so it was the terminology that was wrong here. The OP didn't actually want a multi-part email to be separate emails, he wanted the separate parts to be displayed separately in his email client. After a minor tweak to his code, the email created looks correct - but Gmail is (for some reason) displaying the two parts (one plain text and the other HTML) at the same time.

Comment: I do know what a multipart email is :) I've been using them before with success. I'm trying to move to a different module so it works better with utf8. I did just notice that is has `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"`:, even though I have  `content_type => "text/html",` for one, and `Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"` for the other?

Comment: @AndrewNewby: Perhaps your question needs clarification. You say "I'm trying to figure out why my multipart email all comes out as one email:". I've explained that it's because a mutlipart email **is** one email. I'm not sure what you're actually asking.

Comment: it is supposed to have both a html and plain text email, all in one. So for most people they would see the html version, but for some devices it would show the plain text. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewNewby: You don't mean "email" there, do you? You mean "part". You want a plain text part and an HTML part - both in the **same** email. That's why we're getting confused.

Comment: @AndrewNewby: Please edit your question to clarify this - so other people don't reading make the same mistake you do. Perhaps more coffee isn't the best idea. Take an hour away from the computer. Go for a walk. Watch Netflix. Be with the real people for a while.

Comment: I think I've modified the question to make more sense. WRT to the break - its 10am in the UK =)

Comment: I finally worked it out! I was doing: `Content-Type: multipart/mixed;`, but it needed to be `Content-Type: multipart/alternative;` :) I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the question, but I could try to open up what's going on in there. So the parts you have defined are meant for different content-types and transfer encodings for example attachment's etc. So when you use boundary it can differentiate between these parts that have different content and encodings so it can be interpreted correctly when received. I assume you thought it would split the message to multiple parts and send them separately?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, well its *supposed* to be sending one in html, and the other as plain text - thus:  `content_type => "text/plain",` and `content_type => "text/html",` in the `@parts` bit... but for some reason its trying to send it all as text/plain??

Comment: ah man, I figured it out!!! What a *duh* moment! I had `attributes =>  }` defined at the top of the part, and then also a few lines down. I've merged it all into one for each part, and it works now. Duh!

Comment: Nice, so it defaulted to text/plain? I was gonna suggest to change transfer encoding for the html part next but oh well :) gj

Comment: oh actually, maybe it didn't work :( I've just updated my question above. Its not correctly setting the content-types, but it still shows both on the email. Any ideas?